# Invoke click in a webbrowser element

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a webbrowser control (name: WB) in my VB .net form.

I have loaded a webpage in webbrowser. Here is the sample html:

```
enter code here
<script type="text/javascript">
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize      
('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ScriptManager1', 'form1', 
['tctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UpdatePanel1',   
'ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdatePanel1'], [], [], 90, 'ctl00');
</script>


<div class="row">
<div class="control group alternating">
<h2>Results</h2>
   <div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdatePanel1">

                        <div class="row">
<a  id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1_LinkButton1_0" 
href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Repeater1$ctl00$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
<strong>A. Bleakley Chandler, MD</strong></a><br />
                            Georgia Medical College<br />Augusta, GA, USA
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
<a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1_LinkButton1_1" 
href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;  
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Repeater1$ctl01$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
<strong>A. Kyle Mack, MD</strong></a><br />
Ann and Robert H. Lurie Children's Hospital of Chicago<br />
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
<a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1_LinkButton1_2" 
href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;  
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Repeater1$ctl02$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
<strong>A. Lawrence Ossias, MD</strong></a><br />
                            Mount Sinai NYC<br />
</div>

<div class="row no-shading">
     <div class="pagination-arrows right">
                        <span>
    1 of 100</span>
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1Prev" class="aspNetDisabled ir 
prev">prev</a>
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1Next" class="ir next" 
href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Repeater1Next&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">next</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now I want to click on the first element of Repeater control. My InvokeMember code:

```
Dim pLink As HtmlElement =  WB.Document.GetElementById
("ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1_LinkButton1_0")
pLink.InvokeMember("click") 'doesn't work
```

But due to some unknown reason, the click doesn't fire inside this repeater control. Other links in the page works fine with "invokemember("click")"
like the following one :

```
Dim pLink As HtmlElement =  WB.Document.GetElementById
("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1Next")
pLink.InvokeMember("click") 'Works fine..
```

I tried GeckoFx browser control (geckoanchorelement.click), this did not work. I also tried to send MouseClick thru postmessage api - this also failed.

Comment: WHERE is your `InvokeMember` code being called?  What event?

Comment: I called invokemember in a vb button click event.